# How do I keep my hoppers from filling up when chests are full?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone

I'm not sure how to do this, but i believe it is possible.

Basically, I want to know how to have a chest system, that when a chest is full, (no matter how many items there are per slot) the hopper will stop trying to fil up as well.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: I do not know the exact mechanics but you should be able to work something out with a comparator I believe.. They change their signal based on fullness

Comment: The comparator only works if i have full stacks of everything in my chest. im trying to make it work for all of my items instead of just a specific item.

Comment: So "full" in your case does just mean that all slots are occupied, right? Not that all slots have full stacks in them?

Answer (score 2):

I have outlined a very general case for vanilla mob grinders and such below from my own experience, but you want a sorting system that detects the item inside and either drops the item in or leaves it out. You would probably want to watch Sethbling's video he did on his automatic sorting system on the mindcrack server. His answer to your problem is better in your case (although I believe it is similar to my own):

A Very General Solution to your problem:

Put a different item that will not be processed in the hopper into each of the spaces of the hopper or chest you are trying to not use. That's a bit unclear, so I'll give an example.

For example, if you were doing a skeleton grinder farm, and you only wanted 2 spaces of chest for bones, you would put two bones in the chest, and fill up the rest of the spaces with a piece of dirt, or something you expect not to go into the chest, like one mossy cobble in all spots you don't want to use. Then go to the one hopper that leads to the chest and fill up all its spaces, but one, with another material that isn't dirt or bones, for example, cobblestone. This is to prevent the cobblestone from going into the chest, and let the hopper pick up only bones. If the skeleton drops anything other than bones, it will not be picked up by the hopper, unless the hopper runs out of bones to process, and then might pick up arrows.

Please leave feedback about this answer in the comment section below. Hope it helps!

Comment: Ok, Thank you. although, im trying to store everything of mine, not just a specific item. i just want to use hoppers as a sort of pipe i guess instead of a container.

Comment: In Minecraft, hoppers can do one of three things: (from wiki):
    suck item entities (free-floating items in the world) into its inventory from the space above it
    pull a single item into its inventory from a container above it
    push a single item from its own inventory into a container it is facing

Comment: What you are wanting to do is to pull one item from a chest and put it in another, but "when a chest is full, (no matter how many items there are per slot) the hopper will stop trying to fil up as well." Everything there is straightforward, except for putting "no matter how many items there are per slot". Unless you use command blocks or comparitors to check the amount of items per slot, then minecraft will automatically fill up any available room in a chest from a hopper. I recommend you rewrite your question to specify what you want, that way more people can come answer this

Comment: I've answered the best I can, but here is a link to the wiki page if you're interested: http://minecraft.gamepedia.com/Hopper